# Trouble with the piecewise function - misplaced '&'

Tags: support, mathjax

[image]

I can't understand how I did the piecewise function wrong, I think I've done it exactly like that before. How is the ampersand misplaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$q = \begin{cases} 5x, & \text{ if }55\\ 2x, & \text{ if }41 \end{cases}$$

`$$q = \begin{cases} 5x, & \text{ if }55\\ 2x, & \text{ if }41 \end{cases}$$`

Comment: It looks like you could salvage your formatting by switching changing "start" to "begin".  I chose only to include "if" in the argument of \text, because the number are already formatted within the double-dollars.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the essential difference is? Was the issue that I had dropped down the different lines? Also, I think I replicated this exactly, yet it still shows the same message.

Comment: Aha of course! It was "begin", not "start". Thank you :)

Comment: Indeed!  Glad to assist! :-)

Comment: As a user of TeX.SE. I would to put \text{ if } 55 instead of \text{ if }55.